# Please recommend a good wifi to ethernet device

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, network-adapter, bridge

I need that because I am running a free version of iESX server and there is very little that I can configure in the OS itself. The server is sitting rather far from my router and I want to get rid of that cable.

Now, I have seen a device which is allows to cut a cable with a transmitter and a receiver. Ideally I just want a receiver because my router is already transmitting stuff.

If you have successfully used a wifi to ethernet adapter / bridge, then please recommend it here. Thank you.

Comment: re: "ideally i just want a receiver" -- you need both transmitter and receiver or TCP/IP doesn't work.  (router's transmitter doesn't count -- the server needs one to talk to the router.)  the good news is you probably can't find a device that just does one without the other.  is there some reason you can't just outfit your server with a PCI/PCIe/USB wifi adapter?

Comment: I have found the iESX server (from VMWare) very inflexible. For instance, I am running it off a USB stick, because it would not install on a local hard-drive correctly for some reason (I wasted days on it). So, I do not want to reinstall that what currently works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an old Linksys WRT54G laying around, you can stick [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) on it and it will work as a wireless bridge for you.  This is what I have to do for my AV rack until I find the time to run cables over there.

If you don't have a [compatible router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices), you can try picking one up off eBay or Craigslist for cheap.

Comment: Great! What steps do I need to follow to turn it into a wireless bridge?